# Nginx redirect to hash

Tags: redirect, nginx, utm

I have this vhost in nginx but i need to redirect with `#` (utm parameters) how to do it?

```
server {
    server_name www.example1.com;
    return      301 https://www.example2.com$request_uri; # here I need add utm parameters
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add quotes to the string and it should work.

```
return 301 "https://www.domain.com$request_uri#hash";
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is my actual answer not a suggestion, changed the wording